# What is the difference between 'I'm going to go to work' and 'I'm going to work'

Tags: sentence-construction

Here I have to figure out the difference in the meaning of the following 2 sentences.

**"I'm going to  go to work."**

*" I'm going to work".*

I want to know the 2 different contexts to use above sentences.

Comment: What is *to work*? A prepositional phrase describing a 'location', similar to *to school*?  Or is it the infinitive of the verb *to work*? If you can let me know that much, I can write an answer.

Comment: The sentences can be interpreted a number of different ways.  But if you are comparing them and want to know the difference, "I'm going to work" implies that you are about to start.  "I'm going to go to work" implies an intention to do it at some unspecified future time.  But there are other meanings for which this might not be relevant.  e.g., "I'm going to work" could be a statement of choice: "Are you going to sit on your butt or are you going to work?"  "I'm going to work."  In that usage, they would both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

> "I'm going to work".

This has two possible meanings:
1. Present continuous tense. Going to a location to work, in the present.
2. Future tense. Will "work", in the future. Not about location.

> "I'm going to go to work."

Future tense. Going to some location to work.